# Why does BigQuery implicitly cast one expression but not the other?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery allows this:

```
select '2015-01-01' union all select timestamp '2014-01-01'
```

[image]

However, nearly the same thing with another type errors and doesn't coerce the types:

```
 select 1 union all select '1'
```

[image]

Why is this so? It seems a bit inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is stated in the docs for the `DATE`, `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` types. For example:

> String literals in canonical date format also implicitly coerce to DATE type when used where a DATE-type expression is expected. For example, in the query 
> `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE date_col = "2014-09-27"`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#date_literals

The docs don't state this can be done for the `TIME` type, but in my testing, it also works there. I wonder then why it's not like this for all types (or all non-nested types) if they already do do it for 4 of them.

Comment: I would guess it's because dates/timestamps have a very specific pattern that doesn't vary that makes conversion/comparison/evaluation relatively "easy".  Checking if `x='1'` and `x='01'` and `x='001'` and `x='0001'`, etc etc when you are checking for the integer value of 1 is probably not very efficient and likely more confusing for most query writers.